# Deploy multiple apps with "shared private" Qt frameworks on OS X

Tags: macos, qt, installation, package, qt5

I have a set of applications that work together. It should be possible to start each of these applications individually by the user (i.e. one application provides a monitoring feature, another a configuration feature etc), therefore I would like them to show up in the Applications folder as different applications (possibly within a directory).

The applications are based on Qt5, so I would like to package Qt along with the applications privately to ensure that Qt is present and available. On the other hand I would like to make sure that I only include a single copy of Qt to avoid bloating the system.

I am using a package installer, due to the inclusion of a LaunchDaemon as well.

**How do I place the Qt frameworks needed in order to avoid having multiple copies?**

Here's the naive way:

```
/Applications/
    MyCompany/
        Foo.app/
            Contents/
                Info.plist (must use its own plist to specify some properties)
                MacOS/
                    foo
                Frameworks/
                    Qt-Goes-Here??
        Bar.app/
            Contents/
                Info.plist
                MacOS/
                    bar
                Frameworks/
                    Qt-Goes-Here?? - Or can this be a link to the other location?
```

Since I am not a Mac-guru, any input (including informing me that I am trying something stupid) is very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities here, the first is

```
/Library
```

and the second

```
/Library/Application Support
```

If you look there, you'll find folders with contents for various applications. You should be able to create a folder there and add the Qt Framework, then update your applications to point to that using [install_name_tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html)

The docs state the following for /Library: -

> The Library directory is the top-level directory for storing private
>   app-related data and preferences. There are several Library
>   directories scattered throughout the system but you should always use
>   the one located inside the current home directory. Do not store files
>   directly at the top-level of the Library directory. Instead, store
>   them in one of the specific subdirectories described in this table. In
>   OS X v10.7 and later, the Finder hides the Library directory in the
>   user’s home folder by default. Therefore, you should never store files
>   in this directory that you want the user to access. To get the path to
>   this directory use the NSLibraryDirectory search path key with the
>   NSUserDomainMask domain.

For /Library/Application Support: -

> The Application Support directory is where your app stores any type of
>   file that supports the app but is not required for the app to run,
>   such as document templates or configuration files. The files should be
>   app-specific but should never store user data. This directory is
>   located inside the Library directory. Never store files at the top
>   level of this directory: Always put them in a subdirectory named for
>   your app or company. If the resources apply to all users on the
>   system, such as document templates, place them in /Library/Application
>   Support. To get the path to this directory use the
>   NSApplicationSupportDirectory search path key with the
>   NSLocalDomainMask domain. If the resources are user-specific, such as
>   workspace configuration files, place them in the current user’s
>   ~/Library/Application Support directory. To get the path to this
>   directory use the NSApplicationSupportDirectory search path key with
>   the NSUserDomainMask domain.

The full documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH2-SW9).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I can indeed see application related files in both /Library/CompanyName/ and /Library/Application support/CompanyName/. But the docs says not to place anything directly in /Library, whereas /Library/Application Support is only to be used for non-required stuff? In this case it would be required though - so which of the rules would be best to bend? I'm thinking /Library/CompanyName, would you agree?

Comment: Yes, I would agree with that. One other option is, if one of the apps is a main app and the others are just supporting, then place the framework in the main app and direct the others to its path.